# Find The Parity Outlier using dictionary {Python}

Tags: python, function

during the Kata on Codewars called 'Find The Parity Outlier' I faced a problem, and have been trying to solve it using dictionary. I pass almost all tests except 4.
Instruction for the Kata is:

---

You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

---

The function is:

---

```
def find_outlier(integers):
    d = dict()
    count = 0
    count1 = 0

            
    for i in range(len(integers)):
        if integers[i] % 2 != 0 :
            d['odd'] = integers[i]
        else:
            d['even'] = integers[i]
            
    for j in range(len(integers)):
        if integers[j] % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
        else:
            count1 += 1
            if count > count1:
                return d['odd']
            return d['even']
```

---

Test Results:

1. 2 should equal 1
2. 36 should equal 17
3. 36 should equal -123456789
4. 0 should equal 1

So the question is? Why is it so? Can you help me to sort the problem out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add the input where your algorithm fails to make the question easier to understand

Comment: print(find_outlier([9256481, 9998606, -9662406, 198172, -8707876, -4766470, -2374174, -2423770, -7077162, -9802400, 2304732, -3175032]) This is for example, here is expected: 9256481

Comment: one more:print(find_outlier(-7539177, -8961268, -8841990, -8402296, -2772062, -803058, 2823762, 6997980, -3294564, 2464826, -4501122, -6117694, -4735102, -5090126, 3818142, 5468896, 148362, -3848662, -4363988, 9507046, 9639130, -4064766, -5530460, 4605350, 6186386, -3190042, 3205646, -6218582, -4457184, 1111784, 8125388, 858954, -2145550, -8209990, 4634252]).  Expected: -7539177

Comment: Is your code properly indented? If I indent correctly it works, at least for those two examples

Comment: Do you mean the las condition?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: I made the indention as supposed to be, but still have failed tests. For example this: Testing: [-8209094, 4885381, 7026387, -3574159, 585599, 6783643, -9150169, -8226733, 8879815, -9282929, 5786809, 9012943, -1059053, -3583425, 1382325, 7229515, 3218561, -7927247, 9537709, -5942367, -6135247, 2876897, -4979153, -8749019, 2330973, 3288925, -5365571, -6104389, 9533413].  Expected: -8209094

Comment: @CHim - check out the post and ask if there's any question.

Comment: @CHim did you fix the indentation of the last `if` statement correctly?  It needs to go back **two** tabs compared to what you posted, so that it's outside the `for` loops.  If you only moved it back by **one** tab stop, so that `if count > count1` is done on every iteration of the `for j` loop, that would explain your failures.  The tests you say are failing are **specifically those where the outlier is first in the list**, which means that on the first pass through the `for j` loop, `count > count1` for an even outlier, and `count1 > count` for an odd outlier - which gives wrong answers.

Comment: @CHim - do you find these posts help you, answer your question?  Please ask question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're referring to with that list of test results. In general though, your method with the dictionary seems like it might be overcomplicating things a bit as well. You shouldn't need to use a `dict`, and you shouldn't need two `for` loops either. Here's an alternative solution to this problem using only list comprehension.

```py
def find_outlier(arr):
    # input should be an array-like of integers (and length >= 3) with either only one odd element OR only one even element
    odd_mask = [n%2 != 0 for n in arr] # boolean array with True in the location(s) where the elements are odd
    even_mask = [n%2 == 0 for n in arr] # boolean array with True in the location(s) where the elements are even

    N_odd = sum(odd_mask) # number of odd elements in the input
    N_even = sum(even_mask) # number of even elements in the input

    if N_even == 1: # if even is the 'outlier'...
        return arr[even_mask.index(True)] # return the element of the input array at the index we determined we had an even
    elif N_odd == 1: # if odd is the 'outlier'...
        return arr[odd_mask.index(True)] # return the element of the input array at the index we determined we had an odd
    else: # something has gone wrong or the input did not adhere to the standards set by the problem
        return None
```

And even this is technically not as efficient as it could be. Let me know if you try this and whether it solves whatever issue you were experiencing with expected results.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the final part should not be in the `else` block, nor even in the `for` loop:

```
      if count > count1:
            return d['odd']
      return d['even']
```

Like this is may give a wrong result. For instance, if the first number in the input is odd, and is the only odd one, then this code will return `d['even']` which is obviously wrong.

Place these lines **after** the loop (with correct indentation) and it should work.

However, this problem can be solved without dictionary or extra lists. Have a go at it.

> `def find_outlier(integers):
>      parity = integers[-2] % 2
>      if integers[-1] % 2 != parity:
>          if integers[0] % 2 != parity:
>              return integers[-2]
>          else:
>              return integers[-1]
>      for i in integers:
>          if i % 2 != parity:
>              return i`